# JavaScript : Can't stop a function from running [Tic-Tac-Toe Game]

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, tic-tac-toe

My code is intended to be a Tic-Tac-Toe Game. It's working quite alright: the players can make their moves and the program alerts "Player X won!" when the game is over. But I just can't implement the game draw code nor make the main function called game() stops running once a player wins the game.

I'm a beginner at programming, and I've been struggling with this question: how do I stop a function from running in JavaScript? I have to admit that I'm kinda lost, and I'd appreciate all the help.

The code is the one that follows:

```js
//TIC-TAC-TOE

let tl = $('.tl');
let tm = $('.tm');
let tr = $('.tr');
let ml = $('.ml');
let mm = $('.mm');
let mr = $('.mr');
let bl = $('.bl');
let bm = $('.bm');
let br = $('.br');

var tabuleiro = {
  'tl': tl,
  'tm': tm,
  'tr': tr,
  'ml': ml,
  'mm': mm,
  'mr': mr,
  'bl': bl,
  'bm': bm,
  'br': br
};

function game() {
  var turno = true;
  for (let casa in tabuleiro) {
    tabuleiro[casa].on("click", function() {
      if (tabuleiro[casa].is(':empty')) {
        if (turno == true) {
          tabuleiro[casa].append("<img class='cross' src='cross.svg'></img>");
          tabuleiro[casa].addClass("x");
          turno = false;
        } else {
          tabuleiro[casa].append("<img class='circle' src='circle.svg'></img>");
          tabuleiro[casa].addClass("o");
          turno = true;
        }
      }
      ganhou();
    });
  }
}

function ganhou() {
  if (tl.hasClass('x') && tm.hasClass('x') && tr.hasClass('x') ||
    ml.hasClass('x') && mm.hasClass('x') && mr.hasClass('x') ||
    bl.hasClass('x') && bm.hasClass('x') && br.hasClass('x') ||
    tl.hasClass('x') && ml.hasClass('x') && bl.hasClass('x') ||
    tm.hasClass('x') && mm.hasClass('x') && bm.hasClass('x') ||
    tr.hasClass('x') && mr.hasClass('x') && br.hasClass('x') ||
    tl.hasClass('x') && mm.hasClass('x') && br.hasClass('x') ||
    tr.hasClass('x') && mm.hasClass('x') && bl.hasClass('x')) {
    alert("Jogador 1 Venceu!");
  } else if (tl.hasClass('o') && tm.hasClass('o') && tr.hasClass('o') ||
    ml.hasClass('o') && mm.hasClass('o') && mr.hasClass('o') ||
    bl.hasClass('o') && bm.hasClass('o') && br.hasClass('o') ||
    tl.hasClass('o') && ml.hasClass('o') && bl.hasClass('o') ||
    tm.hasClass('o') && mm.hasClass('o') && bm.hasClass('o') ||
    tr.hasClass('o') && mr.hasClass('o') && br.hasClass('o') ||
    tl.hasClass('o') && mm.hasClass('o') && br.hasClass('o') ||
    tr.hasClass('o') && mm.hasClass('o') && bl.hasClass('o')) {
    alert("Jogador 2 Venceu!");
  }
}

game();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "But I just can't implement the game draw code nor make the main function called game() stops running once a player wins the game."

What do you mean by "can't implement draw code"? does it not draw? Because that does not sound like what the rest of your question is implying. From the look of your code, your problem is that you can still click on the boxes once the game ends? Is this what you are trying ti disable?

Comment: Oh, what I mean is that a player can win the game, but when the board is filled and there is no winners, there is no action at all (I'd want to display some message like "game draw").

Comment: Can't you just add an else after your else if block that alerts the draw message? By the way, the function "game" only runs once.

Comment: @Luple Yes, it is indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use it under the condition that you  win, so if you use an `if` statement, you do `If (what you're testing for) { return; }`

This will just terminate the function.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider.

First thing is the case where there are no moves left.

For this, after a space is clicked, perform a check on each space and if all are occupied, then alert the user. This would be a very niave solution, and you can optimize it however you would like (possibly keep track of the number of moves, and if the number of moves is 9, then its a draw.

Also when the game ends, you may want to consider setting a variable `playing = false` or something like that. Then on click you can check this variable. If it is false then just return. That way when the game ends you can no longer play.

There are many ways of implementing these things, they are just suggestions to solve the problems you are having.